# Making an image to fit its content in the details element for operations dashboard

Tags: qgis

I have configured to display image inside details element in operations dashboard, however, the image is displayed small. I want to make its width to fit its content. How can I do this?
[image]

Comment: Is this GIS related? If so what application or software are you using?

Comment: The application is called Operations dashboard, which is an esri product